# How can I enable mysql_clear_password from Polars via connectorx

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to use Polars' `read_database_uri` function (https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_database_uri.html) to read data from a MySQL database:

```
df = pl.read_database_uri(uri=db_uri, query=query)
```

But them I'm getting:

```
Unknown authentication protocol: `mysql_clear_password`
```

This makes sense because in a SQL GUI app I also have to opt-in into using cleartext authentication if I want to connect to this db.

I'm trying to use the connectorx engine (https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/databases/mysql.html), and this engine is using a driver written in Rust: https://github.com/blackbeam/rust-mysql-simple. This driver has an option to enable cleartext authentication as written on the Github page (search for `mysql_clear_password`).

My problem is that I don't see a way to supply additional options to Polars `read_database_uri` so that I can enable cleartext authentication at the driver level. Is it possible?

Comment: to the extent it can work, it'll be something like adding a bit to the end like `'mysql://username:password@server:port/database?mysql_clear_password=True' or `'mysql://username:password@server:port/database?enable_cleartext_plugin=True` or something.